# Why robotic Lawn mowers are curved body structured?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow, friction

Why robotic Lawn mowers are curved body structured as shown in image  ? Is the curved body structure called aerodynamic ? What's the technical reason for it ?
For reference image :[image]

Comment: Do you want it to snag on bushes or weeds? Also horseshoe crabs are cool.

Comment: Do you think a cube shape would work?

Comment: @Solar Mike , please explain why cube shape won't work ? Just no idea .

Comment: @robin This is why: https://www.123rf.com/photo_170831499_thuja-plant-bush-or-juniper-sphere-shape.html?vti=n6ajfmymz7zs9w7dyh-1-15 Vacuum cleaners are shaped the same way.

Comment: would you buy a lawnmower that looks like a box on wheels, or would you rather buy one that looks like a race car?

Answer (score 1):

The “aerodynamic” shape is likely to allow low branches etc to slide over easily so it does not get hung up.

As for aerodynamics that mower does not go fast enough to have appreciable aerodynamic losses, those due to friction however are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The blade of a typical lawnmower spins around, so the "natural" shape is circular.

From there, you'd want to add on approximately as little as necessary to make room to mount the wheels, motor, and so on. In particular, keeping the outer edge close to the area covered by the blade minimizes the area next to fences, walls, etc., that need to be trimmed separately.

For example, consider mowing around the inside of a curved wall. With a square outline, you end up with a quite a bit of separation between the blade and the wall:

[image]

Curving the corners in allows the mower to get the blade closer to the wall.

Of course, marketing gets involved too--when you're trying to sell a product, can help if customers like how it looks.